# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard'

Tags: android, android-studio, build, android-gradle-plugin

When I try to run my app I get this error message:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard'.> java.io.IOException:
>   Could not delete path 'C:\Users.....'".

I tried to find a solution, but none of them worked. I don't know what it is, what the cause is and how to correct it. Any idea how to fix it?

// here is Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.carmel.mysqlsqllitesync"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
  }
  dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.1'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
compile 'com.joooonho:selectableroundedimageview:1.0.1'
  }
   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: post your gradle file

Comment: i have addes@Mij

Comment: have you tried clean and rebuild project?

Comment: i tried but it did not work until  i restarted the android studio, but  i do not  know what is the cause of this error , do you have an idea?@Mij